How can I make a code appear on the header of just one page?
I'm trying to get a code to appear only on one page (though the URL does say post=4315 even though I'm pretty sure it's a page not a post). The code is in the header of the site (code below). How can I do this?
<script id="mcjs">
    !function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/db2e7f5a6f13c1ca0590c5030/21a00c59167e1cc5c1847c037.js");
</script>     


All WordPress content whether built-in content types like Posts, Pages and Attachments or custom post types you may add (depending on the site that might be Reviews, Recipes, Books etc) lives in the wp_posts table and is identified by the post variable in the querystring. You may want to visit Settings > Permalinks and set a more legible structure.

If you have access to WordPress files, you can add this code to your theme's functions.php file:
function add_code_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page( 4315 ) ) { // The ID of your page is 4315
        ?>
        <!-- Your code here -->
        <script>
            !function (c, h, i, m, p) {
                m = c.createElement(h), p = c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0], m.async = 1, m.src = i, p.parentNode.insertBefore(m, p)
            }(document, "script", "https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/db2e7f5a6f13c1ca0590c5030/21a00c59167e1cc5c1847c037.js");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_code_to_specific_page' );

If you don't have access to your theme's functions.php file, you can install the Insert Headers And Footers plugin, and add the following code to your header using that plugin:
if ( is_page( 4315 ) ) { // The ID of your page is 4315
    ?>
    <!-- Your code here -->
    <script>
        !function (c, h, i, m, p) {
            m = c.createElement(h), p = c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0], m.async = 1, m.src = i, p.parentNode.insertBefore(m, p)
        }(document, "script", "https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/db2e7f5a6f13c1ca0590c5030/21a00c59167e1cc5c1847c037.js");
    </script>
    <?php
}

